# Why use "*(*(array + i) + j)" over "array[i][j]" in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

In what example situation I should use the trickier form of it? Does it generate a faster binary code? If I can do the job with the [][] notation, should I still make an extra effort for some reason and implement it with pointers?
For single data I understand the need of pointers. I am asking specifically for two dimensional arrays and not about the general sense of using pointers.

Comment: When you are entering an Obfuscated Code contest

Comment: Use that only if you hate the people who will have to maintain that code.

Comment: I know this is a joke, but caution on that, @MikelF .Leaving behind poison-pill code has a way of following you around as you go job hunting. Plus you never know when a vengeful ex-employer will use it as testimony against you in a lawsuit.

Comment: @user4581301 Should I understand that writing poorly readable code could result to be illegal?

Comment: @NIki the code's not illegal. It's used as proof that you either A) didn't know what you were doing and thus misrepresented yourself and shouldn't be paid, B) Wrote the code in bad faith and shouldn't be paid for it, C) were damn sloppy, not living up to your obligations and shouldn't be paid. Never underestimate the lengths to which a weasel will go to get out of paying a bill or recoup costs.

Comment: @user4581301 For my experience the _weasels_ don't look in at that depth of point and knowledge usually (they don't even understand what you're doing). You're only a bad number in an excel sheet, that makes the overall cost calculation bad.

Comment: @user4581301 You are telling me this in a moment I am considering to abandon my studies in programming and study something else. I am in the first 20 of the hardest academy in my country, but I don't like factors unrelated to the programming itself. the ones you mention are just part of a large list. I'll just say that it is seems to me a profession way more stressful than one I would like to practice for living.

Comment: I just wanted to say that I am good at the programming itself, but maybe I expressed myself bad with this "in the first 20"
(I mean the programming itself is not my problem)

Comment: Hey, if you got into a top school you're already doing well. Most of my problems along that line came as a contractor. Tried my hand at the life of a consulting engineer and did OK. Didn't like it.  I wanted to write code, not business plans. Worked for big companies and little companies as an employee. There's less overhead, working for others but no matter where you go, what job you take in any field, you will always have to take on a bit more outside your interests than you'd like.  Some one will need a schedule. A costing. Politics. It's the same at flipping burgers at McDonalds and Cray.

Comment: I guess you are right, and I should "flip my burgers" without complaining so much. I'll try...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In what example situation I should use the trickier form of it?

**Never**, unless you're attending a code obfuscation contest as mentioned in [@M.M' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036361/why-use-array-i-j-over-arrayij-in-c#comment71246910_42036361)

> Does it generate a faster binary code?

No, the emitted assembly instructions should be the same with any decent compiler.

> should I still make an extra effort for some reason and implement it with pointers?

No. Use standard containers or smart pointers instead. Refrain to use raw c-style arrays and pointers.

For known sizes the simplest way is

```
std::array<std::array<T,5>,10> array2D;
```

For 2D arrays variying in size you can use

```
size_t rows, columns;
std::cout << "Enter row and column size please > " << std::flush;
if(std::cin >> rows >> columns) {
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> array2D(rows,std::vector<T>(columns));
}
```

---

To optimize 2D arrays to use contiguous dynamic memory blocks, consider to write a small wrapper class, that translates row and column offsets into the internal value positions (e.g. maintained in a simple `std::vector`).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @πάντα ῥεῖ's advice, it's preferable to write C++ expressions so similar types may be substituted for the variables — the principle of *generic code*.

`std::array` is a preferred alternative to C arrays. (The two-dimensional case looks like `std::array< std::array< int, M >, N >`.) It doesn't support the `+` operator, so the obfuscated expression would obstruct migration to it, or any other container-like type such as `std::vector`.

Comment: the two-dimensional case of std::array isn't POD-compatible though, unlike single-dimensional vector, memory of which we can supply to API that requires pointer to array. Thankfully, there are not many APIs that use two-dimensional arrays (if you're not dealing with CAD systems at least)

Comment: Clarify? C++ POD = standard-layout and trivial. `array<T,N>` is POD for POD T (unless it has a nonstatic data member other than the array, which is pathological). This includes the two-dimensional case. On the other hand, `std::vector` is never POD. The only way to guarantee ABI compatibility with a C library is to use types from C such as two-dimensional C arrays — but it's UB to alias such an array onto a `std::vector` sequence (or, equally, onto a `std::array` of one or two dimensions).

Comment: std::vector<T>  and std::array<T,N> have contiguous storage and provide direct access to underlying array  via data() method, but std::array< std::array< T, M >, N > doesn't. It have contiguous storage in reference to std::array< T, M >  which is non-POD obviously. it's not UB to use pointer, returned by data() in way, reverse to one  I wrote in  my answer below, as multidimensional arrays also are guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: @Swift `array` *is* typically POD. Why wouldn't it be? The pointer arithmetic of going off the end of a sub-array into the next sub-array is UB. Casting a storage blob to multidimensional array type violates strict aliasing and incurs UB.

Comment: array is  of objects of certain type,  fundamental, other array, struct or classes, so POD or not POD depends on what it is consists of. It is explicitly allowed to access stored value by an lvalue expression that  _have a character type_ or compatible value type. Managing platform \ implementation defined issues in this case is under programmer's control only.

Answer (score 0):

There is generally no reason to prefer the `*(array + i)` form over the `array[i]` form.   Similarly, there is no reason to prefer the `*(*(array + i) + j)` form over `array[i][j]`.

Semantically they are equivalent, and the compiler is able to emit the more effective "binary code" - which will normally be the same in both cases.

Practically, human beings usually find it easier to understand the `array[i][j]` form, so that is preferable unless you are seeking to confuse people (e.g. obfuscation).

It is vital, when using other forms of pointer arithmetic, to understand the equivalence.  That allows more effective choices of technique.   It is not an accident that C++ standard library supports iterators (a generalised form of pointer) to work with ranges, and that using these are often encouraged over simple `array[i]` syntax,.

Answer (score 0):

When you explain how 2d array works. That expression is counter-example of possible mistake using array's name if array is multi-dimensional. Let's say, it's not a rare mistake. What many inexperienced programmers do:

```
int arr[10][20];

for (int I =0; I<200; I+=1) *(arr + I) = <some value based on I>;
```

In best-case scenario, they encounter  " cannot convert from 'int' to 'int [20]" error and go to their better (or to SO website ). In worst-case, they  become "clever" and use type-cast to trick the compiler.

They know of how single dimensional array work, because it is in every book since K&R, and they don't realize that they go out of array bound as soon as I becomes larger than 9. The expression

```
*(*(arr + i) + j)
```

shows that indexes of array are multiplicative in relation to the pointer  to which array's name degraded. More "proper " way to do what they want is to  use pointer to int:

```
int  *p = (int *)&arr[0][0];

for (int I = 0; I < 200; I++) 
    *(p+I) = <some value based on I;
```

But strictly speaking, C++ standard doesn't guarantee this either, unless you use pointer to unsigned char.

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)&arr[0][0];

for (int I = 0; I < 200; I++) 
    *(int*)(p + I*sizeof(int)) = I;
```

Still must be careful here, in case of  platform supposes padding and elements of array are actually  of type that requires padding at end (e.g. a struct).

If we output resulting array:

```
cout << "arr[][] = { ";
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
 {
     cout << "\n{";
     for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) 
         cout << arr[i][j]<< " ";
     cout << "}";
 }
 cout << "}\n";
```

We'll get:

```
arr[][] = { 
{0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 }
{20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 }
{40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 }
{60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 }
{80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 }
{100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 }
{120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 }
{140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 }
{160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 }
{180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 }}
```